# jQuery/Javascript : Change onclick of an achor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I want to change `onclick` event of an anchor but I can't get it working using javascript.
Here is what I am trying :
`document.getElementById("CommCo").onclick = "GetComments("+id+");";`

Edit : Sorry everyone but I asked for changing the value of it, Not the event handler itself. Anyway Thanks to all of you.

Comment: What do yo mean "change"? Did you want to convert this to jQuery syntax?

Comment: You used 'jquery' tag, but in the code you have not used anything about jQuery.

Comment: What do you mean by _Get it working_? What is it you expect to happen? What is not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's just the value of the attribute, use

```
document.getElementById("CommCo").setAttribute('onclick', 'GetComments('+id+');');
```

If you want to change the event handler of the 'click' event, do

```
document.getElementById("CommCo").addEventListener( 'click', function() { 
   GetComments( this.id ); 
});
```

If you want to do it in jQuery

```
$('#CommCo').bind( 'click', function (ev) { 
   GetComments(id); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I think everyone got my question wrong. I asked for changing the value not the handler. Now it does change perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Assigning the `onclick` property through javascript expects a function:

```
document.getElementById("CommCo").onclick = function() { GetComments(this.id); };
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/RKUt7/).

---

If you plan on using jQuery, here is the syntax for binding an event:

```
$('#CommCo').bind('click', function(e) {

    // 'this' in here is the element that was clicked

    GetComments(this.id);

});
```

- `'#CommCo'` is the ID selector in jquery
- you can also use the method `.click()` which internally calls `.bind('click', ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try with JQuery

```
var idvar = 1234; // Some ID
$("#CommCO").bind("click", {id:idvar}, function(event) { getComments(event.data.id); });
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery:

```
$('#CommCo').on('click', function() {
    GetComments($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Question is tagged with jquery so, I'll show how do that in this framework:

```
$("#CommoCo").click( function() { GetComments( this.id ); } );
```